# how to write PHP module in C

Tags: php, c, php-internals, php-extension

how can i write my own module in C ?
is it possible ?

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021

Comment: if you have posted the comment as an answer i will be able to vote up and select it as answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [where can i learn php internals, how they work ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389738/where-can-i-learn-php-internals-how-they-work)

Comment: Old question but since 2014 you can also use PHP-CPP library (www.php-cpp.com, Apache license) to simplify the writing of PHP extensions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here's an old article that I used when I wrote my first extension:

http://web.archive.org/web/20110222035803/http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021

Things may have changed since then, so you may want to search for similar tutorials for additional references.

Oh, and this should be useful:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php